# Nagios: Error in config file - First line (NULL Value)

Tags: chef-infra, nagios, cookbook

I'm running Nagios 3.5.1 and I'm getting an error saying there's an error in my config file.

When I run `nagios -v /etc/nagios3/conf.d/hosts.cfg`, I get this error

> Reading configuration data... Error in configuration file
>   '/etc/nagios3/conf.d/hosts.cfg' - Line 5 (NULL value)

Line 5 is the first like with content. Lines 1-4 are comments.
When I remove 1-4, the error moves to the first line still. And commenting out the first host just moves the same error lower.

My hosts.cfg is not complicated

```
 define host {
   use server
   address 10.203.130.187
   host_name production-mgmt-nagios-server-20140325-10-203-130-187
   hostgroups all,linux,nagios-server
 }
```

and so on.

Simplifying with one host or even the example host gives the same error.

Creating a new file and typing a basic version gives the same error.

Running out of ideas and anything will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. As per the documentation for Nagios 3.x for [configuration verification](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/verifyconfig.html) you are to run the following command:

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

And assuming you have no errors or warnings that might cause issues restart Nagios. The restart command will depend on your OS Flavour.

Answer (score 4):

Always an easy solution that takes forever to find.

Don't run `nagios -v` on hosts.cfg. Run it on nagios.cfg
That gives proper errors to debug.

Turns out I had some backups that nagios was picking up into as config files.

```
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios3/conf.d/testconfig.cfg'..
```

Deleted and ran smoothly. 
Hope this saves someone time.